# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream :: Proxying api calls?

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have an app in a nginx based docker container, and I'm trying to route api calls to a server on a different dns name. I'm getting this because of this code that I added to my nginx.conf. Does anyone know a way to go about what I'm doing, or see what the could of my issue could be?

```
  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://www.api.test.example.net:8080;
  }
```

Both serves are being hosted on AWS ECS.

Comment: Server is able to resolve DNS name `www.api.test.example.net` correctly?

Comment: Can you check records using `nslookup www.api.test.example.net` ?